# how to open batch file, write a command and then press enter in vbnet

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I don't know how to do this and anything that comes up on Google isn't what I need.Can someone please tell me how to open a batch file, write a command and then press enter to execute the command in vb.net? Here is the code is has so far:

```
    Process.Start("example.bat", "example command")
```

I have no more than this, and it's really confusing me, can someone please show me the right way about this?

Thanks,

Comment: The "write a command" is confussing. Batch files are commands one after the other. What you are trying is to include an aditional command in the list, pass an argument or give input to something being asked from the batch file?

Comment: it's alright, i fixed it by just making a batch file with the commands

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but using Notepad or Notepad++ is good for creating Batch files. All you have to do is write your code go to File>Save As...>click on "All Files">file_name.bat make sure you type .bat at the end or it will not work